# How to create multiple timer function on the fly and use setInterval for all

Tags: javascript, jquery

My requirement is like i'll be getting jsonobject with having count say {noOfInputToCreate:3} and I need to create those many input elements and increase the count for all.

Here is sample code which will make you to understand the requirement.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery   /1/jquery.min.js?ver=2.4.3'></script>
<input class="interval1" value=0><br/>
<input class="interval2" value=0>

<script>
function interval1(){
 $(".interval1").val( parseFloat( $(".interval1").val() ) + 1 );
}
function interval2(){
 $(".interval2").val( parseFloat( $(".interval2").val() ) + 1 );
}

intervalId1 = window.setInterval("interval1()",1000);
intervalId2 = window.setInterval("interval2()",1000);
</script>
```

If you look at the above code, the functions interval1() and interval2() are pre-defined. So what I am looking is I should be able to create these on the fly as per no of inputs I need to create and attach setInterval for the same.

Or else It could be single function. but the problem I'll face will be like calling setInterval multiple time using this same function.

Can any one help or provide some suggestions around it.

Comment: Why don't you use a common class for all these inputs??? FYI, MSDN is ugly when it comes to WEB dev, that's just horrible: `window.setInterval("interval1()",1000);`

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a single interval timer to call multiple arbitrarily defined functions, then you can create an array of functions and when your interval timer fires, you simply call all the functions in the array.

```
var fnList = [];

var timer = setInterval(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < fnList.length; i++) {
        fnList[i]();
    }
}, 1000);
```

The, you can add as many functions as you want to the list:

```
fnList.push(interval1);
fnList.push(interval2);
```

---

FYI, there's no problem with also just using multiple `setInterval()` timers, one for each function.

---

And, your particular issue looks like you could probably write just one function that would process all the fields you want to process by just putting a common class `class="interval"` on each field you want to process.

```
var timer = setInterval(function() {
    $(".interval").each(function() {
        this.value = parseFloat(this.value) + 1;
    });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Just to add to my requirement, I want to stop as well at some point of individually.  Let's say after 1 min I want to stop first and then after 2 mins I want to stop another.  Also I don't want have those functions pre-defined. it should be like I want to create them on the fly.

Comment: @Mrbond - In my first option, you can selectively remove any function you want from the `fnList` and it will stop being called.  In my second option, you can selectively add or remove the common class name from any element and it will start or stop being processed.  I think it's all there for you.  In my first option, you can add any function to the `fnList` at any time.

Comment: I agree with you, but still I have to have those functions pre-defined and count should match with the one I will get in json.

Comment: @Mrbond - In my first option, you can add functions to the array at any time.  They don't have to all be known in advance.  Beyond that, it is not clear what else you're asking for.

Comment: I mean, before hand I have to declare functions like  interval1(),interval2().  That will work if I have {noOfInputToCreate:2}. Now suppose in response I get {noOfInputToCreate:10} then in that case I should have interval1(),interval2()..... interval10() pre-defined. -Thanks

Comment: @Mrbond - you don't have to have `10` functions that all do the same thing, but operate on a different element.  You can have one function that you pass the element to or as my last option suggests, you can have one function that finds all elements with a common class name on it.  So, insert as many input elements as you want and given them the common class name and the ONE function will operate on all of them.  You should never be making N functions that all do the same thing except operate on a different element.

Comment: Then in that case how I would be able to stop counter for particular element.

Comment: @Mrbond - If you're using the class name approach (the last option in my answer), you just remove the class name from any given element and it will stop being incremented.  Add the class name and it will again be incremented.  Kind of elegant if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a class to function recursive settimeout.

```
   function increment(class){
        $("."+class).text(parseInt($("."+class).text())+1);
        setTimeout(increment,1000);            
    };
```

Comment: This isn't going to successfully process multiple elements independently like the OP's original code.  This will assign them all the same value.

Comment: Just to add to my requirement, I want to stop as well at some point of individually. Let's say after 1 min I want to stop first and then after 2 mins I want to stop another. Also I don't want have those functions pre-defined. it should be like I want to create them on the fly.